# How to write in a csv through tkinter's entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, python-3.6

So I have this program I want to write from two `tkinter` `Entries` to the newly created `csv` file from `pandas`. So far I failed to write a single line except for the two columns I set in the `Dataframe`.Is there any way for every line that is created by `external1` `Button` to represent the `csv` file?

The `buttonmain()` function consists of a `Frame` named `line`, two `Entries` and the two `Buttons` that are shown at the end of the code.

```
def forget_show():
    external1.pack(side='right')
    external.pack_forget()

def savedata():
    x = e1.get()
    y = e2.get()
    print(x, y)
    with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
        fields=['First', 'Second']
        w = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fields)
        w.writerow(x)

external = Button(line, text='Save', command=lambda: [savedata(), forget_show()])
external1 = Button(line, text='+', command=lambda: [buttonmain(), external.pack_forget()])
external.pack(side='right')
```

The `Dataframe` looks like this:

1. `criteria` is an empty `list`
2. `entr1` and `entr2` are two `Entries` that the user set the name of the file.

`df = pd.DataFrame(criteria, columns=['First', 'Second'])
filename = entr1.get() + ' - ' + entr2.get() + '.csv'
df.to_csv(filename, mode='a', index=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,what you are asking is quite unclear at the moment but if you need your result to look like this

```
First,Second
Value1,Value2
Value3,Value4
```

Then in you `save_data` function you could:

```
with open(file name,'w') as f:#or better still open the file in 'a' mode
    line = ','.join([x,y])
    f.write(line)
```